# get command line perl command to report what changes it's made

Tags: solaris, perl

I am using the following command (on Solaris) to remove the protocol from a bunch of files.

```
find .  -name "*.txt"  -exec perl -pi  -e 's/http//g' '{}' \;
```

Is there a way to have a verbose output so I can get a report of which files have been edited?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Can you just add `-print` to the `find` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get a count of substitutions per file with:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -e '
    $count{$ARGV} += s/http//g;
    END {for (keys %count) {print "$_: $count{$_}\n" if $count{$_}}}' {} +
```

Note that in that and in your original solution, `perl` will rewrite the files regardless of whether it does substitution in them or not.

Don't use `;` to terminate the `-exec` command. `perl` can handle several files at a time, no need to call one perl per file.

If you only want that output without actually doing the substitutions, just replace `-pi` with `-n` in the command above.

You could also do:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -c http /dev/null {} +
```

To get a count of *lines* containing `http` (not necessarily the same as the number of `http` occurrences).

Comment: Thanks for that Stephane.  The only thing is, I was hoping to get the report first (without substitution) by dropping the -i, but that just lists all lines in all files.  Is there an easy way to get the report of what will be substituted?  This is going to be run on a LOT of files so I want to be sure I am doing the right thing.

Comment: @user2609641, replace `-pi` with `-n`. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a report of what files are sent to perl by using both `-print` and `-exec`:

```
find .  -name "*.txt" -print -exec perl -pi  -e 's/http//g' '{}' \;
```

If you want to find out which files were modified, then something like

```
find .  -name "*.txt" \
    -exec perl -i.bak -pe 's/http//g' '{}' \; \
    -exec sh -c 'cmp -s "$1" "$1.bak" && echo "$1" || rm "$1.bak"' _ '{}' \;
```